# jQuery CheckBox Always Returns False

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am trying to take a checkbox from within an ASP.NET page, change the value to 1:0 and write to a SQL DB.  Every time I get the value of the checkbox it comes back as false.

```
var checked = $('.CheckBoxOldSealIntact').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

always returns 0

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxOldSealIntact" runat="server" CssClass="CheckBoxOldSealIntact" />
```

I have tried several other methods as well with the .attr(), .prop(), .checked but I get different issues with each one.  I'm hoping there is something small that I am just missing here.

Comment: And if you do `$('.CheckBoxOldSealIntact').length` what does that return ?

Comment: n.b. you can just write ~~$('.checkbox').is(':checked') to output 1 or 0

Comment: I also tried doing the .is() and it would always come back as unchecked as well.  When I try to use .length it comes back as 0 it appears as well.

Comment: If the `length` is zero, then the selector isn't finding the element.. Does the javascript execute before the DOM is ready? And what does the html output (not the asp markup) of the checkbox look like?

Comment: HTML is as follows

Comment: <span class="CheckBoxOldSealIntact"><input id="MainContent_CheckBoxOldSealIntact" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$CheckBoxOldSealIntact" /></span>

Comment: So `$('.CheckBoxOldSealIntact')` selects the `span`, which of course cannot be `:checked`. Try `$(.CheckBoxOldSealIntact input)`

Comment: Adding the input fixed it!  Thank you so much Jason P!

Answer (score 1):

Please You have two way to identify checkbox checked or not .

1. When you are using server side control then use below syntax .

   ```
    var checked = $('#<%=CheckBoxOldSealIntact.ClientID%>').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
   ```
2. Use Html input checkbox .

   ```
   <input  type="checkbox" value="Isvalid" checked="checked" id="abcd"/>
   ```

   sytnax of jquery of html input checkbox:

   ```
     var checked = $('#abcd').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
   ```

Thanks and Enjoy .

Answer (score -2):

Use the following:

```
var checked= $('#CheckBoxOldSealIntact').is(':checked');
```

The variable "checked" will then be a boolean value.

Replace the selector with the appropriate value (in the case of ASP.NET client Ids which might be emitted differently at runtime.

Comment: The polite thing to do if you are going to downvote an answer is to at least mention why you think it's not useful.